# How do I add an optional selection criteria to a SAP HRFORMS print program?

Tags: sap-hr

I'm trying to add a checkbox to the standard payadvice driver program to enable the user to e-mail the form instead of printing it.

Because the print program is automagically generated from the print form (transaction HRFORMS), I can't just go and change the program.

Within transaction HRFORMS I have some control over the selection screen via Optional Selection fields below:  Is it somehow possible to add a custom selection criteria to this via config?

[image]

I could wrap the generated program in a custom program of my own, but then I would lose a lot of the existing configurability.

Answer (score 0):

I have been unable to find a configurable solution.

However, SAP already provides a standard wrapper program for HRFORMS:

```
H99_HRFORMS_CALL
```

I enhanced the selection screen in this program using implicit enhancement points, and passed the necessary parameters to the print form using Parameter ID's.